# How to filter an array and extract the values which are equal to another array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array from API which has lot of string values. I have another array which has the values I needed. How to extract only the values from the API array which matches my array.

```
API array1= ["abc", "xyz", "jkl", "lmk", "ajudsi" ...]; 
my array2 = ["abc", "jkl"]
```

I want to check each value of the API array1 with my array and filter the values which matches my array2.

My filtered array should be:

```
array1 = ["abc", "jkl"]
```

Any idea how to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach to filter your match values

```js
var filterFunction = ["abc", "xyz", "jkl", "lmk", "ajudsi"].filter(
    function(e) {
      return this.indexOf(e) >= 0;
    },
    ["abc", "jkl"]
);
console.log(filterFunction);
```